# VBA Worksheet Calculate IF statement not working

Tags: vba

Does anyone have any idea why the code below is not triggering?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()

Application.EnableEvents = False

If [J92].Value = 0 Then
    Call Test

End If

Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Thank you,

Comment: a couple of things to check.  1.  the code is on the correct worksheet.  2.  the value in J92 is being populated by a formula. 3.  Make sure EnableEvents is on(it can get turned off and stay off if the code errors)

Comment: 1.5 the active worksheet must be the one with J92 and the code.

Comment: Thank you for the assistance.  This active sheet is actually NOT the one without the code.  Is there a workaround on this/any advice?

Comment: @EthanDangler Just specify which sheet it is: IF Thisworkbook.sheets("SheetName").range("J92").value =0 Then ...